# Images in user notifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

How do I create user notifications with cocoa that contain Images. Like Airmail or Alfred does?
For instance Airmail includes a contact image in the mail notification if the one is present:

[image: Airmail notification]

I haven't found any documentation how to add this via code. Do I have to use a custom notification center?
I have found the [CNUserNotification](https://github.com/phranck/CNUserNotification) project but when I use it the notifications won't show up in the notification sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

If you create user notifications using [NSUserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html), on Mavericks +, setting `contentImage` does the trick. Strangely enough it's not documented, but it's exposed and in the release notes. OS X 10.8 or less would necessitate a custom solution.

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
notification.contentImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"imageNamed"];
```